# Moment JS Angular 2 - after 24 hours just show normal date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, momentjs

I am trying to put together a chat application and I have never dealt with momentjs before. Basically I want it to show that a comment was posted seconds ago, minutes ago, hours ago.. but then I need it to just show the date rather than 1 day ago, 2 days ago etc etc...

I am using angular2 to build the app (also quite new to it) and dealing with javascript date objects is kind of tricky.. has anyone ever done this before ? let alone with Angular2.. i have tried the following but something is off.. no errors but its just not calculating it correctly

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'formatDate2'
})
export class DatePipe2 implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

            let result:string;
            // current time
            let now = new Date().getTime();

            // time since message was sent in seconds
            let delta = ( now - value ) / 1000;
            console.log(delta);
            // format string
            if (delta < 10) {
                result = 'jetzt';
            } else if (delta < 60) { // sent in last minute
                result = 'vor ' + Math.floor(delta) + ' Sekunden';
            } else if (delta < 3600)
            { // sent in last hour
                result = 'vor ' + Math.floor(delta / 60) + ' Minuten';
            } else if (delta < 86400) { // sent on last day
                result = 'vor ' + Math.floor(delta / 3600) + ' Stunden';
            } else { // sent more than one day ago
                result = 'vor ' + Math.floor(delta / 86400) + ' Tagen';
            }
            return result;

  }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact relation between momentjs and your question? It's never used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've tagged this with momentjs, here's how you would do what you're after with momentjs. You can include a localized version of momentjs to display german messages instead.

```js
var tenSecAgo = moment().subtract(10, "seconds");
var twoDayAgo = moment().subtract(2, "days");

function showSinceOrDate(date) {
  var now = moment();
  if (moment.duration(now.diff(date)).asHours() > 24) {
    return date.format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm");
  } else {
    return date.fromNow();
  }
}


console.log(showSinceOrDate(tenSecAgo));
console.log(showSinceOrDate(twoDayAgo));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

[Also have a look at moment's documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)